# How to restore Innodb database?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I physically moved the database and now I am not able to restore Innodb database.

I am getting this error-

```
140131 13:03:41 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table table_t1/t1#P#p0 from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem.
```

Help me to restore this db

Answer (score 0):

Put it back and move it through the SQL interface (e.g. `RENAME TABLE`).